# Firebase server side rending example for nuxt.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have created small nuxtjs app using firebase. I'm having hard time setting up nuxtjs build with firebase cloud function. I found this video but it is outdated (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYUWsjUxxUQ&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkbvTj8AUUCfBO7DoEHJ-ME&index=9).
Any help or guidance or documentation would be helpful.

---

Here is link for the repo which. Also I mentioned steps which I tried to follow.
https://github.com/bhargavkonkathi/nuxt-ssr
Here are the things that I've tried with this repo:

```
 1. Install dependencies inside src using yarn install
 2. Install dependencies in functions folder
 3. Run yarn build inside src it will create nuxt folder inside folder.
 4. Copy and move all contents from functions/nuxt/dist/client folder to public/client folder.
 5. Now run functions serve --only functions,hosting -p 5004
 6. You should see build firebase hosting running and build running.
 7. Deploy firebase deploy --only functions,hosting.
```

This is the link which I able to deploy after it is running. As you can see vuetify is not working properly. I'm getting few issues.

Deployed link
https://ssr-bumps-testing.web.app/

Comment: Unfortunetaly, this falls under the "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" reason of closing a question. You should come to us with an actual technical issue and some upfront effort at trying to attempt to host it yourself.

Comment: Hi, I didn't want to be mean. It's just that I'm used to this kind of moderation and I see a lot of questions daily. Nonetheless, it's more of a Stackoverflow thing to flag those kind of posts, it's not my own rule (can find more info on meta SO). I try to help people daily here. Meanwhile, we do need debugging material to help people with their issue. Seeing that the OP did a decent amount of effort to scope and provide the best question is always better for both parties too. If you could update with your Vuetify issues, I will be pleased to remove my close vote for this question.

Comment: Hey @kissu, I found solution my self only. Anyways thanks once again for your time. I'm closing this question.

Comment: A question cannot be closed but you can post your own answer and accept it. It will help other people.